# Could java enum class implements "Comparable" interface?

Tags: java, class, enums, compilation, comparable

Seems that enum class already has a `final` compareTo function, which cannnot be overriden. But my requirement is to customize an enum class like this:

```
enum Operator {
    Add('+', 1),
    Sub('-', 1),
    Mul('*', 2),
    Div('/', 2);

    private char op;
    private int priority;
    private Operator(char _op, int _priority) {
        op = _op;
        priority = _priority;
    }
}
```

Then I wish to have it implements Comparable interface to have the ability to compare among `Add`, `Sub`, `Mul`, etc. But seems I cannot use `implements Comparable<Operator>` as described above, javac gives compilation error:

```
Redundant superinterface Comparable<Operator> for the type Operator, already defined by Enum<Operator>Java(16777547)
```

So how to achieve my goal? Thanks.

Comment: why would you need that? looking at your code, you should be using your priority to check that

Comment: Maybe you can provide a small example of how this enum is intended to be used?

Answer (score 0):

You can always declare `Comparator.comparingInt(Operator::getPriority)` and use it to compare your operators.

Answer (score 0):

> Then I wish to have it implements `Comparable` interface to have the ability to compare among `Add`, `Sub`, `Mul`, etc

You can't change the implementation of `Comparable` in your *enum*.

Every *enum* implicitly implements `Comparable` because its parent `java.lang.Enum` has implemented this interface and method `compareTo()` is marked with `final` modifier, i.e. you **can't override** it.

Here is the quote from the [*Javadoc*](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#compareTo(E)):

> `public final int compareTo(E o)`
>
> Compares this enum with the specified object for order. Returns a
> negative integer, zero, or a positive integer as this object is less
> than, equal to, or greater than the specified object. Enum constants
> are only comparable to other enum constants of the same enum type. The
> **natural order** implemented by this method is the **order in which the constants are declared**.

You can define a `Comparator` implemented based on the `priority` property as `public static` field.

```
enum Operator {
    MUL('*', 1),
    DIV('/', 1),
    ADD('+', 2),
    SUB('-', 2);
    
    public static final Comparator<Operator> BY_PRIORITY = 
        Comparator.comparing(Operator::getPriority);
    
    private char op;
    private int priority;
    
    Operator(char op, int priority) {
        this.op = op;
        this.priority = priority;
    }
    
    public char getOp() {
        return op;
    }
    
    public int getPriority() {
        return priority;
    }
}
```

If you need the order to reflect the standard order of arithmetic operations: *Multiplication/Division* comes before *Addition/Subtraction*, then the value of `priority` of the `MUL` and `DIV` needs to be lower than the value of `priority` of `ADD` and `SUB`.

The names of enum-member `Add`, `Sub`, etc., as well as names of constructor parameters `_op`, `_priority` in your code are not aligned with the [*Java naming convention*](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/codeconventions-namingconventions.html).

Comment: _property priority is redundant_ actually, it's not :) There are only 2 values for 4 constants. Seems to indicate the operation precendence (mul/div before add/sub).

Comment: @kleopatra Thanks, I've missed that point. Multiplication should have no precedence over division, so we can't use the *natural ordering*. Fixed the answer.

Comment: @Holger Right, my interpretation was incorrect. I've updated the answer. I guess the question of using an unum without taking advantage of its natural order is opinionated, but in this particular case it still feels a bit fishy because arithmetic operations do have their own order: *parenthesis*, *exponent*, *multiplication/division*, *addition/subtraction*. Wouldn't it be cleaner to create a private nested class that implements `Comparable` and defines all the operations as static final fields?

Comment: I consider a `Comparator` cleaner, because this order definitely differs from equality. In practice, I never had a reason to compare operators by priority because it is simpler to have a parser producing an AST reflecting the precedence in the first place. Like with Java’s grammar which defines the precedence rules implicitly.

Answer (score 0):

## Why compare method is final

As you noted correctly, you cannot override the compare function of the enum class, because it is final.

The method is final, because of the semantics of an enum (Enumerated).
It represent a number of values that could be completely substituted with there "ordnial" value. Actually, most applications of enum work with the ordinal value only. The names are just to make it easier to handle them.

Thus, the natural sort order (that is defined by the comparable interface) is to order by Ordinals and not on some field values. Actually, most enums don't have fields at all.

So if you find your self in a spot where you need to order enums based on something other than there ordinals, you should probably reconsider using enums ...

## What you could do:

I'm going out an a limb here, since you didn't exactly specify what your final goal here is, but in most cases someone tries to implement Comparable, they try to sort a List or Array.

If that is the case, you could just work around that issue using a Comparator.
Both the Array.sort, Collections.sort and Stream.sorted method have a overload that accepts a Comperator to define the sort order.

So what you could do is add a method to your enum like

```
 public static int comparePrio(Operator first, Operator second) {
        return Integer.compare(first.priority, second.priority);
    }
```

and then call the sort method like this:

```
Collections.sort(myListOfValues, Operator::comparePrio);
```

(Code for Arrays and Streams is analog)

Warning: The code is not null save. If null is a possibility, you need to add additional null checks in your comparePrio method